# selecting column names where data is not null or blank

Tags: sql-server-2008, names

SQL Server 2008

I have a table `MyTable` with columns `A, B, C, D`

When I select a row I want a list of only those columns with non-null/blanks. The result set would be

```
A
C
D
```

if `B` was null in my row.

Actually, there may be a column `E` someday. But I can get all possible column names from another table and need to check if `MyTable` has any of them and if so which ones have data for the row I selected

Thus:

```
select * from MyTable where ID = 6

select ColumnName from AllColumnNames
```

- For each `ColumnName` in the result

  - if `ColumnName` exists in `MyTable` AND there is data in it `where ID = 6`, add `ColumnName` to output.

There's gotta be a way to do this in one query?

Comment: The only way I can think of easily doing this is with dynamic sql

Answer (score 3):

This will convert your table to XML in the CTE and then it uses XQuery to find the node names that does not have empty values. This will work if your column names does not break the rules for XML node names.

```
;with C(TableXML) as
(
  select *
  from MyTable
  where ID = 6
  for xml path('T'), elements xsinil, type
)
select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as ColumnName
from C
  cross apply C.TableXML.nodes('/T/*') as T(X)
where T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') <> ''
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59187

Add this the the where clause if you want to exclude the ID column as well.

```
T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') <> 'ID'
```